# How to call GWT-RPC method in native android app?

Tags: android, gwt

Can I use GWT(Google Web Toolkit) RPC like a webservice?

I want to call services in native android apps, but GWT RPC use it's own protocal.

Comment: Please have a look at [Google Web Toolkit and Web Services: The XML Way](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188080/Google-Web-Toolkit-and-Web-Services-The-XML-Way)

Comment: Read [Extending GWT RPC to do more than just basic serialization](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.in/2010/07/gwtrpccommlayer-extending-gwt-rpc-to-do.html)

Comment: Find the discussion on [GWT, RPC and consuming Web Services](http://www.codenes.com/blog/?p=78)

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/. This project has an Android library that allows GWT-style service calls from Android (or any java client) to a GWT RemoteServiceServlet. As a disclaimer, I built the Android library for this project and currently manage it.